# Review deleted answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, declined-flags

I [recently reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3383347) an answer on "First Posts" queue. I press flag (because it was not an answer) but I have only the moderator option.

I flagged for moderation explaning the situation and my flag got rejected. Looks like the answer was deleted before I press the flag link.

[image]

I think it should notify somewhere that the answer was already deleted, don't you?

Comment: What I always tell people: if the option you were expecting isn't there, reload the page and you'll probably find out why.

Comment: @animuson The same I said to Servy: But the same way it identifies that it only has to show the moderator option, it would be better to include if the answer was deleted instead of reloading the page, if it's possible. Don't you think?

Answer (score 4):

Simple race condition.  The post was not deleted when you loaded the review, it was deleted by a mod while you were looking at it, and then you flagged it.  Because the post was not deleted when you loaded the review, there really isn't any behavior here to fix.

Had the mod noticed this when reviewing your flag they could potentially have marked it as helpful, but it's certainly reasonable for them to have not realized that you were reviewing an item or that you were shown the post before it was deleted.  (How would they check this for every flag?)  It's just one declined flag, don't worry about it.

Comment: I hate it when I lose a race (condition)!

Comment: @AndrewBarber Yeah.  Clearly the solution is to stop taking time to think when reviewing. If you always choose an action as fast as you can possibly click it then you won't have that problem.

Comment: But th same way it identifies that it only has to show the moderator option, it would be necessary to include if the answer was deleted, somewhere

Comment: @SysDragon That would mean having a different flag dialog from the flag dialog seen anywhere else.  As it is the flag dialog is doing the same thing that you're doing when flagging any normal post, and flagging a deleted post is a perfectly acceptable thing to do.

Comment: @Servy What? No. I mean somewhere you can see the answer has been deleted. The same way the flag dialog changes showing only the moderator option. But it could be shown anywhere.